# NoClassDefFoundError when building jar file

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-mail

When I try to build a jar file from my Application it gives me the following exception:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class de.ff.JavaMailTest.SendEmailTLS
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/mail/MessagingException.
```

The Class works fine if I run it in IntelliJ. Here is my Code:

pom.xml

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-   4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>de.ff</groupId>
<artifactId>JavaMailTest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>de.ff.JavaMailTest.SendEmailTLS</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
</project>```
````

SendEmailTSL.java:

```
    package de.ff.JavaMailTest;

    import jakarta.mail.*;
    import jakarta.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
    import java.util.Properties;

    public class SendEmailTLS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
        final String username = args[0];
        final String password = args[1];

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.web.de");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,
                new jakarta.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setRecipients(
                    Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(args[2])
            );
            message.setSubject(args[3]);
            message.setText(args[4]);
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Succes");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to build Jar file which specifies `Main-Class` attribute.

You can create is **Manually** or by using **Assembly plugin** or using **IntelliJ**

1. Creating runnable jar manually - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html
2. Creating runnable jar using Assembly plugin - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html
3. Use following steps to create runnable jar using IntelliJ

Following are the steps to do it using IntellIj -

1. Open Project structure dialog (File -> Project Structure)

[image]

2. Select Artifacts option from Project settings

[image]

3. Click + button to add `Jar` artifact and select `From modules with dependencies`

[image]

4. Select your main class in `Create JAR from modules dialog` and click OK

[image]

5. Save your configuration by Clicking OK

[image]

6. Click `Build Artifacts` from `Build` menu and and Select `Build` in submenu

[image]

[image]

7. Now run the built Jar file which should run without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are getting the exception when running the jar file. You are getting that jar file because the jar file doesn't have the javakata.mail library included within it.

You can either specify the dependencies into classpath when running the jar file. Or, in order to bundle the dependencies within the jar file, you can use maven assembly plugin to create a exploded jar file(the .classes from dependencies will be extracted and zipped inside the jar)

Run it with `mvn clean compile assembly:single`

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>de.ff.JavaMailTest.SendEmailTLS</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```